# Perform Multiple logics on a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Trying out java 8 streams . Is it possible in streams to find the count of elements starting with X , Y , Z from a List which contains a lot of elements.

```
transactions.stream()
            .filter(e -> startsWith("X"))
            .count();

transactions.stream()
            .filter(e -> startsWith("Y"))
            .count();

transactions.stream()
            .filter(e -> startsWith("Z"))
            .count();
```

The above code gives the count of elements starting with X,Y,Z in the list but in the above case i'am iterating through the list three times to get the data's. This could be done by iterating the list just once using a simple for loop. Is it possible to do all these conditions in a single stream [iterating just once] instead of using multiple streams ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't use streams for that. But if you must, have a look at this code:

```
Map<String, Long> collect = transactions.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> {
    if (t.startsWith("X")) {
        return "X";
    }
    if (t.startsWith("Y")) {
        return "Y";
    }
    if (t.startsWith("Z")) {
        return "Z";
    }
    return "none";
}, Collectors.counting()));
```

will print something like

```
{X=1, Y=1, Z=1, none=1}
```

For the specific case

Comment: _"I wouldn't use streams for that"_, but that's what you are using !

Comment: I'll just note that, if the criteria is always the the first character, it would be much simpler to return `t.charAt(0)` as a classifier.

Comment: @AlexisC. because that was the question. That's why I wrote "[But] If you must...."

Comment: @JornVernee True. But that's not "multiple logics" any more ;)

Comment: @steffen Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Why you wouldn't ? It's a typical groupby/reducing operation and I think it's a task that is perfectly suited for the stream API as your answer shows.

Comment: @AlexisC. Limited extensibility (it's for counting only), it requires an intermediate map, plus the usual things like horrible stacktraces, less intuitively debuggable etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one, it could find all the type of the first letter.

```
Map<String, Long> collect = transactions.stream()
                                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, 1), Collectors.counting()))
```

Not only 'X', 'Y', 'Z', but also 'a', 'c' or any first letter of the element you give.

Finally, you can use the `get` method to get what you want, like this below:

```
collect.get("X");
collect.get("Y");
collect.get("Z");
```